# Start value for vector loop

Tags: c++, loops, vector, iterator

Say I have the following:

```
int numFields = 0;   
for ( auto & isFieldBlank : InputProcessor::numericFields_isBlank ) {
    if ( !isFieldBlank ) {
        numFields += 1;
    }
}
```

`InputProcessor::numericFields_isBlank` is a `bool` vector of all numeric input values indicating whether the input values are empty `true` or populated `false`.

I have two related questions:

1. Is there a better way to count the populated fields in the vector?
2. Is there a way to provide a starting index to the for loop iterator?

Comment: It is not possible to use a range-based `for` loop to iterate over elements of a `std::vector<bool>` by a simple reference.   You will need to use another type to hold the information if you want to use a range-based loop with a reference.   You can use `auto &&` though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A range based for loop will always run the entire range, you cant change that unless you adapt the range.  What you can do though is use [`std::count`/`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) to count the instances for you like

```
auto count = std::count(container.begin(), container.end(), true);
```

and to change the start and stop positions you can use `std::next` to move the iterator like

```
auto count = std::count(std::next(container.begin(), some_value),
                        std::next(container.end(), -some_other_value),
                        true);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to count the populated fields in the vector?

You can simplify the body of the `for` loop to:

```
    numFields += (!isFieldBlank);
```

The complete `for` loop will be

```
for ( auto & isFieldBlank : InputProcessor::numericFields_isBlank ) {
    numFields += (!isFieldBlank);
}
```

> Is there a way to provide a starting index to the for loop iterator?

You certainly can. However, you will need to use a normal `for` loop, not a range-`for` loop.